# How can I see the "call out" when clicking on Windows 7 buttons?

Tags: windows-7

There are a few buttons in Windows 7 that I want to know more about. So, what process or command is Windows 7 calling when I click on it? For example when I click on the Properties button what is Windows actually doing? I need the exact commands (not for the Properties but for other buttons)

I know that there are some special programs to track stuff like that.

Any tips how I could find out more?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to buttons on a screen (as opposed to keyboard buttons).
That is handled by onClick events of whatever window or system currently has focus.
A good windows monitor tool is included with the various Visual Studio suites, called WinSpy.
This allows you to see which program gets which event (here a mouse click) and which process is associated with which window, pane or component.
How each program deals with that click depends on the program and context. So you'll have to be very specific. In your example, properties of a file, the windows system will look up attributes of the selected file and present them in a new window.